# Do an event when user has stopped typing into a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I want to do an action after user is finished typing into a text input, but ignoring the delete key.

I can "wait" for the user to finish typing into the text input by using underscore's `debounce` function.

I need to also listen to make sure the delete key wasn't used, and that is where my code seems to breakdown.

Here is what I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/4Wn8L/:

```
var lazyChange = _.debounce(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode != 8) {
        console.log('User entered a key that wasnt backspace!');
    }
}, 300);

$('#appPreview').on('keyup', 'input', lazyTripChange);
```

Comment: https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/debounce

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<input type="search" class="lazy-search">

$(document).ready(function() {

  var thread = null;
  var delayMs = 500;

  function doSearch(str) {
    console.log('search: ' + str);
  }

  $('.lazy-search').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8) {
        clearTimeout(thread);
        var target = $(this);
        thread = setTimeout(function() {
            doSearch(target.val());
        }, delayMs); 
    }
  });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HfY2N/1/ (check console)

"When the user presses a key create a timeout which does a search after n milliseconds, but if the user presses a key again before that count has expired then clear it and create another one"